# Snippet to promote a session scope cas table to global scope

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Can someone help me to answer these three questions?

1. snippet to load a sas dataset from sashelp.cars to cas public.cars (session scope)
2. snippet to load a sas dataset from sashelp.cars to cas public.cars (Global scope)
3. Snippet to promote a session scope cas table to global scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all these snippets, you'll need to run the following code at least once first:

```
cas;
libname public cas caslib='public';
```

**1. Load sashelp.cars as public.cars: session scope**

```
data public.cars;
    set sashelp.cars;
run;
```

**2. Load sashelp.cars as public.cars: global scope**

```
data public.cars(promote=yes);
    set sashelp.cars;
run;
```

**3. Promote a session scope table to global scope**

```
proc casutil;
    promote 
        casdata   = 'cars' 
        incaslib  = 'public'  
        outcaslib = 'public' 
    ;
run;
```